# Нет подходящего первичного или уникального ключа

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Пытаюсь создать таблицы, но жалуется, что нет подходящего уникального или первичного ключа.

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT by 1),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    cat_id VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_category PRIMARY KEY (id, name, cat_id)
);
CREATE TABLE manufacturer
(
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT by 1),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    site VARCHAR(255),
    description BLOB,
    CONSTRAINT pk_manufacturer PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
);
CREATE TABLE product
(
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT by 1),
    name VARCHAR(100),
    model VARCHAR(100),
    quantity NUMBER,
    price DEC(9,2),
    availability VARCHAR(1) CHECK(availability IN('y','n')),
    cat_id VARCHAR(20),
    manufacturer VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id, cat_id, manufacturer),
    CONSTRAINT fk_product_cat_id FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)
        REFERENCES category(cat_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_product_manufacturer FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer)
        REFERENCES manufacturer(name)
);
```

Comment: И правильно ругается, внешние ключи (foreign key) могут ссылаться только на что то, уникально определяющее запись. В таблице category у вас уникально идентифицирует запись только связка из 3х полей, (id, name, cat_id), так как именно их вы указали в первичном ключе. Отдельное поле cat_id не уникально, значит адресовать им запись невозможно. Задайте правильные первичные ключи. В первой таблице я бы сделал первичным одно поле id и ссылался бы соответственно из других таблиц именно на него

Comment: @Mike Все то же самое можно было бы написать в поле "ответ" :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что стоит исправить.

1. Таблица `category`: непонятно, в чем смысл существования двух полей - `id` и `cat_id`. Одно из них лучше убрать или переименовать, потому что в таком виде они сбивают с толку. Также изменить первичный ключ - оставить одно поле:

   ```
   CONSTRAINT pk_category PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ```
2. Таблица `manufacturer`.
   Изменить первичный ключ (оставить одним полем), если нужна уникальность названия (она часто нужна в подобных случаях) - сделать дополнительное ограничение:

   ```
   CONSTRAINT pk_manufacturer PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT uq_manufacturer_name unique (name)
   ```
3. Таблица `product`.
   Остается только поправить типы столбцов и внешние ключи:

   ```
   cat_id number,
   manufacturer_id number,

   CONSTRAINT fk_product_cat_id FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)
       REFERENCES category(id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_product_manufacturer FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id)
       REFERENCES manufacturer(id)
   ```